# Check the php Session when a user accesses a certain subfolder

Tags: apache-2.2, php, login, login-script

I have a login script using a php session under `mydomain.com/login.php` . Whenever a user accesses something inside the subfolder `mydomain.com/internal/` I would like to automatically check whether he is logged in (with a custom php script) in order to redirect him to the login page if he's not logged in. Is that somehow possible?

In case it is easier, I would be happy to simply run the custom check-logged-in script before any php script is called under the whole domain.

I am using apache2 on a debian machine.

PS: I am currently adding an include statement for the checked-logged-in script at the head of each file in the `internal` subfolder. But this is a bit tedious and has the disadvantage of being rather prone errors (if I forget it when adding a new site).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the php.ini setting `auto_prepend_file`. It can also be set using php_flag in your apache configuration so it happens only for one virtualhost.